# Memory usage in Dual GPU(Multi GPU)

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, hpc

I am using two GPUs of same configuration for my HPC GPGPU calculation using OpenCL. One of the card is connected for the display purpose and about 200-300 MB of memory is always used by two programs called compiz and x server.
 My question is , when using these GPU's for computation I can use only a partial amount of total memory in GPU which is used for display purpose whereas the 2nd GPU I am able to use entire Global memory.
 In my case I am using two Nvidia Quadro 410, Which has 192 cuda cores , 512 MB as memory but  503 MB usable . In case of display GPU i can use only 128MB for computation and other I can use full 503 MB for calculation.

According to the [The OpenCL Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.0.29.pdf) Page 32

> Max size of memory obj
>   ect allocation 
>   in bytes.  The minimum value is max 
>   (1/4
>   th
>    of 
>   CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE
>    , 
>   128*1024*1024)

Also shouldn't this hold good for all the GPU's present in the System?

Answer (score 2):

Just continue to read from that point, you will see

```
Max size of memory object allocation
in bytes. The minimum value is max
(1/4th of
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE ,
128*1024*1024)
```

so whichever is greater, 128MB or  1/4 of total; will be the limit.

Comment: Ok, this solves the memory usage of my primary GPU. What about my secondary GPU (which is not connected to my display ) which I want to use for computational purpose , how am I able to utilize entire Global memory size?

Comment: Are you sure there is no shared memory from system RAM in bios settings?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I ran matrix multiplication program on my 2nd GPU , and cross checked it with nvidia-smi and nvidia x server. Both showed memory utilization . And when I gave values more than its Global memory, as expected I got CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES

Comment: Maybe nvidia changed drivers so it has internally seen as 2GB but just overflows after 500 MB?

Comment: You see I am using an entry level Quadro 410 Card as my primary and secondary GPU. As you mentioned , in my **primary GPU** i can use maximum 128 MB , anything more than that gives me "out of memory" error , whereas when it comes to my **Secondary GPU** I am able to use 500 MB of memory , which happens to be my **Global Memory** [Quadro 410 Specs](http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro-410-graphics-card.html#pdpContent=2)  .   <br>   Also with totally another work station I connected This Quadro 410 as display GPU , and Zotac GTX 960 for computation purpose. Even here i noticed the same.

Comment: I tried  800 MB float array buffers on both my cards, even the display card worked. Both have 2GB vram. There must be something happening with beta drivers maybe? These are amd though. Max is between 1200 and 1400 MB I dont know why. Maybe it is changed in driver side and not told to khronos. I am sending this to both devices: float[] a1 = new float[1024*1024*320]; and it must not be working but it is working.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL will automatically swap data out or it the GPU, so you are not actually limited to the GPU global memory, you can have more memory used, as long as you don use it all at once. You can "obviusly" not create objects such big that don fit on the GPU memory. That is where this limit kicks in.

The current max limit per object is as pointed out by @huseyin

> **CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE (cl_ulong)**
>   Max size of memory object allocation in bytes.  The minimum value is max 
>   (1/4 th of CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE, 128*1024*1024)

```
minimun_max_global_size = max(1/4*global, 128MB)
```

If you read it carefuly, is the min value for the max allocation size.(tricky wording!).
Probably nVIDIA is setting it to 1/4 on a display GPU, and to whole memory size on the non-display GPU. But nVIDIA is following the spec by doing so in both cases.

It is something you should query, and operate within the limits the API reports. You cannot change it, and you should not guess it.

Comment: How can you confirm / prove when you say `"to all memory size on the non-display GPU"`    <br> I have been working on OpenCL for quite sometime. I wasnt able to find any document which explains why I can use complete Global memory from my secondary GPU.

Comment: It is up to the driver implementation, other manufacturers may do differently, and even other version of nVIDIA driver. The Spec just defines the minimum value the maximum should have, and the definition is per device. So it is free to the driver to have different values on different devices according to its criteria, it is not a bug, and it is not something that can be fixed or changed, or even guessed in advance. My personal guess is that since the second GPU is a "helper" GPU, all its memory is allocated for OpenCL/CUDA, but it is just my guess to why the driver is behaving like that...

Comment: Yes it is minimum, nearly 1500 MB is accepted(nothing more) for a 2GB amd card. Just tried.

Comment: @huseyin Why did you delete your answer. It was good only. should have kept it

Comment: @pradyot ok i undeleted but darkzeros' answer supersedes it imho. I would accept his answer. He found tricky word!

Comment: @DarkZeros Your answers here are always extremely accurate and helpful, but I have to ask this time: Can you provide me any documentation which supports your statement "OpenCL will automatically swap data out or it the GPU"? I know a number of people who share that understanding but cannot find it documented anywhere. Are these automatic transfers visible in a tool like Nsight? Are you saying that 8 programs can each allocate 25% of the GPU memory and still function (just more slowly)?

Comment: @Dithemaster I can´t provide any documentation right now.. ill try to find it and update my comment. Most drivers move the buffers around to different devices or even CPU when needed. Just an example, if your output buffer of GPU 1 is used in a kernel in GPU2 CL will transparently move the buffer there. Also there is no real mechanism to allocate a buffer in a device, it is just allocated in the context. But provably you are just right, and it is not guaranteed, a driver implementation can just failed to allocate, end of story...

Comment: I am still not convinced with this answer :(